# mongodb regex uppercase five letter

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm having trouble trying to write a query that returns all capital five letter codes in mongodb. I have this so far:

```
db.foo.find({f : {$regex : [/[A-Z]{5}/] } }).count()
```

It is not correct though as the result it returns is the size of the whole collection and I know there are at least 4000 entries not in upper-case. I haven't had much experience using regular expressions so I'm struggling to see what's going wrong.

Comment: No, removed it now, I must have pasted an old version.

Comment: It still needed to be as the above query doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thihnk your regex is wrong, try:

```
db.foo.find({f : {$regex : /[A-Z]{5}/ } }).count()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `$regex` operator unless you're trying to perform multiple $ operations at a time.

```
db.foo.find({f: /[A-Z]{5}/})
```

Will work just fine.